# Intel/AMD hybrid graphics on Ubuntu 16.04: How activate the other one?

Tags: radeon, hybrid-graphics

My laptop has two GPUs: an integrated intel and a Radeon HD 8550M. The latter is from [Radeon HD 8000 series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radeon_HD_8000_series). According to the manual of the open source Radeon driver, these series are supported by the driver. I want to use the Radeon GPU, but the integrated GPU is being used by ubuntu and the applications, and I don't know how to activate the Radeon. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

just type in console:

```
DRI_PRIME=1 application name
```

Comment: Please elaborate your answer and explain what actually doing this command line.

Comment: Now, the application reports that it's using the AMD GPU, but when it opens its OpenGL window, the system freezes.